# extract *.b64 file using java

Tags: java, base64

I am using OpenSSL to create a digital signature. This produces a *.b64 file which contains the file *.txt and this inturn contains the digital signature.

How do I extract a *.b64 using java?

Comment: OpenSSL usually has many choices of output formats...you should choose one that is more suited to your needs.

Comment: OpenSSL's b64 format is a base-64 encoding. Apache Commons Codec has a decoder for base-64. See http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29): to decode the base64-encoded file contents to get the digital signature:

```
String fileContentsStr = ...
byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(fileContentsStr);
System.out.println(new String(decoded));
```